# Criterion of Dahlquist and consistency of a process

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

> We have the linear multi-step process
>
> $-y_k-y_{k+1}+y_{k+2}+y_{k+3}=4hf(t_k,y_k)$
>
> for the initial value problem $y'(t)=f(t,y(t)), y(0)=0$
>
> Check the consistency of the process and the criterion of Dahlquist of the characteristical polynomial.

Checking the criterion of Dahlquist is easy.
The characteristical polynomial of this process is given by:

$\rho(x)=x^3+x^2-x-1=(x-1)(x+1)^2$ with the roots $\lambda_1=1$ and $\lambda_{2,3}=-1$.

So $|\lambda_i|\leq 1$ but we have a double root with $|\lambda_2|=1$ so the criterion of Dahlquist does not apply here.

I struggle with the consistency of this process.

I have to show that for

$\tau_h(t,y(t))=\frac1h\sum_{j=0}^m \alpha_j y(t+jh)-\sum_{j=0}^m \beta_j f(t+jh,y(t+jh))$

it is

$\lim_{h\to\infty} \tau_h =0$

Correct?

Is there an easier way?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A linear multi-step method is consistent iff $\rho(0)=0$ and $\rho'(1)-\sigma(1)=0$, in your case $\rho(x)=x^3+x^2-x-1$ and $\sigma(x)=4$
So $\rho(1)=0$ $\rho'(1)-\sigma(1)=3+2-1-4=0$ and  and your method IS consistent

PS: Sorry for my previous blunder, I had the exam for this a few week ago, and I don't know how I could mess that up :(

Comment: Thank you. I thought this rule only applys for a specific consistency order and not for consisteny in general. Which mistake do you think I made. I checked with the task sheet and every thing seems at the right place.

Comment: At your edit: No, it is meant $4hf(t_k, y_k)$. Thanks again, for your answer.

Comment: In my textbook it says it applies to all lineal methods, I don't know if it's a mistake, to me it's not totally obvious how you show $\lim_{h\to\infty} \tau_h =0.$

Comment: I have this formulation: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3268659/characteristical-polynomial-of-a-multi-step-process

Comment: Ah, I just see, that you write $\sigma$ instead of $\rho$. I think $\rho(x)=x^3+x^2-x-1$ so $\rho(1)=0$ would hold. Is this a mistake?

Comment: I also wonder about this task, because showing consistency is normaly hard work, and this task is at most giving 1/2 out of 4 points, so there has to be an easy way.

Comment: I saw this when I was writing the answer and forgot afterwards, I was sure you made a mistake. Now I am sure I made a mistake! xd. I'll edit it, sorry

Comment: No problem. {}{}

Comment: Show consistency is usually hard work, however in the lineal methods you have many criteria that help you get the answer easily(specially the $C_p$ criterion that you discussed in your previous post)

Comment: Good to know. I start to see how usefull this criterion is. Do you mind taking a look at this question too: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3268703/convergence-of-a-multi-step-process

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95178/discussion-between-miraunpajaro-and-cornman).