# Convergence of a multi-step process

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

> We have the linear multi-step process
>
> $-y_k-y_{k+1}+y_{k+2}+y_{k+3}=4hf(t_k,y_k)$
>
> for the initial value problem $y'(t)=f(t,y(t)), y(0)=0$
>
> Show that for $f=0$ and $y_0=y_1=y_2=0$ converges the process.

Sorry for all the questions lately, but I really want to understand this topic, but here I am lost again, because I do not know what $y_0, y_1$ and $y_2$ mean here.

What do I have to do, to show convergence?

Hints are apprechiated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can your iteration at any time move away from $y_{k+3}=0$?

Comment: @LutzL I am sorry, I do not understand that question...

Comment: If all the other data is $0$, $f(y_k)$ and $y_0,...,y_{k+2}$, what interesting value can $y_{k+3}$ only take?

Comment: @LutzL If I had to guess it would be $0$, but I do not want to take a guess... Sorry, but I have no clue. I take a look into my notes.

Comment: The exact solution is $y(x)=0$, and you get $y_k=0$ for any $k$ for a given step size, and then that for any step size, so convergence is trivial.

Comment: So this gives that the first iteration is $0=0$, so what you're trying to do is solve the following IVP $y'(t)=f(t,y(t)), y(t_1)=y_1=0$. Now, with a small-enough step the solution of this IVP is as close as you want as the original IVP(since when $h\rightarrow 0, t_1\rightarrow0$). Some estimation could we obtained via the Gronwall inequality for mathematical accuracy. I'll have to work out the details

Comment: @LutzL Ah, I see. What I did not had in mind is, that we have a recursion, which explains $y_0=y_1=y_2=0$. I thought this refers to $y_k, y_{k+1}, y_{k+2}$. How do I see that I get $y_k=0$ for every $k$ and step size?

Comment: @LutzL Why does this not contradict, that convergence implies stability?

Comment: I'm confident that consistency and stability implies convergence. Have you a source for the reverse statement? Anyway, that you get convergence or exact solutions for the basic examples does not imply that you get convergence in all cases.